# spray-testkit === status passes whatever status is

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-dsl, spray-test

I have following test in spray-testkit with scalatest and I do not understand why test passes every time despite the actual status.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.event.LoggingReceive
import akka.testkit.TestProbe
import com.ss.rg.service.ad.AdImporterServiceActor.{GetImportStatus, StatusOfImport}
import org.scalatest.{MustMatchers, WordSpecLike}
import spray.http._
import spray.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest


class AdServiceApiTest extends WordSpecLike with MustMatchers with ScalatestRouteTest {

  "AdService REST api " must {
    "POST for import with mandatory parameters should be processed" in {
      val p = TestProbe()
      val addressServiceMock = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[AdServiceActorMock], p.ref))

      Post("/service/ad/import?adId=1") ~> new AdServiceApi(addressServiceMock).route ~> check {
        handled must be(true)

//        rejections must have size 1
        response.status === StatusCodes.NotAcceptable
      }
    }
  }
```

Test passes even though that status should be different and when I made the test failed for obvious reason like rejection ... the error msg is follows:

```
Request was not rejected, response was HttpResponse(202 Accepted,HttpEntity(text/plain; charset=UTF-8,The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.),List(),HTTP/1.1)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: Request was not rejected, response was HttpResponse(202 Accepted,HttpEntity(text/plain; charset=UTF-8,The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.),List(),HTTP/1.1)
    at spray.testkit.ScalatestInterface$class.failTest(ScalatestInterface.scala:25)
```

Seems that I am missing some important concept here.

Could someone please clarify?

UPDATE: Following works correctly

```
status must equal(StatusCodes.Accepted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`===` is not enough.  You have to write

```
status should === (StatusCodes.NotAcceptable)
```

or

```
assert(status === StatusCodes.NotAcceptable)
```

Comment: Adding a little background, === is just a type-safe equals method and as such it does not throw exceptions (nor should it).

Comment: Compiling with `-Ywarn-value-discard` could help catch this kind of problem.